# Is there a way to load javascript scripts concurrently?

Tags: javascript

Probably not. But still would be nice to have it. Kinda hard to believe that modern standards do not support it.

**Update**: I would like to load scripts concurrently as opposed to the asynchronous scripts execution. So that if there are 10 scripts to load (9 small, 1 big) - in that case the big script won't "stuck" the download of the smaller ones.

**Update2**: I am loading the scripts by adding the `script` DOM element via javascript.

Comment: Are you talking about downloading scripts or about single-threaded interpreters?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to achieve by this?

Comment: thanks for your questions. kindly see my updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referencing them via `<script>` tags in the delivered HTML, then it's up to the user agent to decide how to load this resource, but every modern browser is able to fetch multiple resources concurrently.  Interestingly they may choose not to fetch multiple *Javascript* files at once - [this Google best practices document](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#PutStylesBeforeScripts) alludes to why, though the exact behaviour will depend on the browser,

If you're programmatically loading them via logic in other Javascript files, then probably not - Javascript is inherently single-threaded, so no two scripts could execute at once in order to fire off the requests.

Answer (score 3):

In html5, you have `async` attribute.

[HTML5′s async Script Attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async)